# JFET I drain vs V gate to source curves

Tags: datasheet, fet, iv-curve

Why there are several curves on next image (datasheet for 2SK170)? What condition changes to use one or another curve?

[image]

Comment: Are you building the Simplistic NJFET RIAA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idss is what is different. Idss is a characteristic of the individual JFET, much like hFE of a BJT varies from one unit to the next, and much like hFE the JFETs are 'binned' into three broad ranges so your circuitry does not necessarily have to deal with the entire roughly 10:1 range (the 2.6~20mA range only applies at 25 degrees C junction temperature).

[image]

Comment: What is the full of abbreviations: GR, BL, V on datasheet?

Comment: That means you might pick one unit and it will be 2mA Idss at high Tj and the next 2SK170 might be 20mA when cold. The variation with Tj is another 20, 30, 40%, plus and minus, depending on the required temperature range. The GR etc are markings on the parts, and you may be able to specify which bin you want (at a premium). I don't know what the designations mean, if anything, maybe something in Japanese. Similar codes are used for Japanese BJTs.